# Logout button reboots the machine

Tags: centos, xfce, session

On CentOS 7.4 running XFCE, most of the time if I click the Logout button, it will reboot/poweroff the machine.

It does the same thing if I use the Logout button in the xfce panel or in the application menu.

I even get sometimes the issue when I use the command:

```
xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

How can I debug this?

The `/var/log/messages` does not really yield anything of interest, except that it seems the computer shuts down during the process of stopping services, without warning.

Note that sometime, it manages to reach the user login screen, and then proceed to power off.

Comment: You tell nothing about your problem. Which Logout button ? In the application menu? Action button? What you try? Where you look for? You can try to ask [here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php) with more details.

Comment: I'll add infos.